# Condition within the if-else statement being evaluated incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I've got something like these in one of my functions and it returns false.

```
if ((X = ax && Y == ay) || (X == bx && Y == ay) || (X == cx && Y == ay) || (X == ax && Y == by) || (X == cx && Y == by) || (X == ax && Y == cy) || (X == bx && Y == cy) || (X == cx && Y == cy))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

However if I call the function with the same parameters, but changed code to only this, it returns true.

```
if (X == bx && Y == ay)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Why is this happening? The condition in second code is one of the conditions in first code, so If one of them is true it should return true, am I right? I expect the first condition to return true

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but you are missing an equals in the first condition.

Comment: Could you please post your actual code. I can't see the issue from your "something like these" snippet.

Comment: try `if ( (X == bx) && (Y == by) )` for the second case. Otherwise the compiler will probably interpit it as `if ( ( (X == bx) && Y ) == by)`

Comment: Precedence of these operators is: `==` > `&&` > `||` > `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator, it is a common mistake to accidentally use it for comparison, which is also your case. In the first part of your condition: `(X = ax && Y == ay)` you change the value of `X` by assigning `ax` to it, which then affects the result of the rest of the condition.

Also note that:

```
if (A || B || C || D)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

is equal to:

```
return (A || B || C || D);
```

Comment: +1 for getting rid of "return true" !

Answer (score 5):

That "=" right near the beginning of the long condition needs to be a "=="! You're assigning a new value to X rather than just testing it, which is causing all the other tests to fail.

Comment: Will that fix the problem though? Why would that cause it to be false?

Comment: Yep, see second sentence of answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if((X = ax && Y == ay) ||  //Problem is here
```

You need to make it

```
if((X == ax && Y == ay) ||
```

Your code is failing for `X` =  `bx` and `Y` = `ay` as in the first case, the value `ax` gets assigned to `X`, which is `TRUE`, but `Y` is not `ay` which makes the first comparison false. All comparisons after that evaluate to false which causes the first test to fail.